# Is there a way to take a look inside a NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

All is in the question, i would if it is possible to look in a NSManagedObjectContext in order to look how many Entity is actually in etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to browse the contents of your context interactively, you can do that with [F-script.](http://www.fscript.org/)